# How to fix a TabError

Tags: python, tabs

I have no idea why it keeps saying

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

At the line

```
counter = 0
```

If I remove 'counter = 0', it works.

```
if counter < 3:
    counter = counter + 1
elif counter == 3:
    send_mail()
    counter = 0
```

Seriously I don't know what is wrong lol!

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ just Notepad++, but its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use either all spaces or all tabs for your indentation, as the error message says.

Tabs and spaces, or using tabs at all for indentation, is considered bad practice in Python.

You would probably benefit from [a good text editor or IDE](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-text-editors-1564907215) that will show the difference between tabs and spaces, and automatically insert spaces for you while you code.

Comment: have you made sure to replace any tabs in the file with spaces?

Comment: Specifically the indentation of "send_mail()" should match the line "counter = 0".

Comment: I think you misunderstood. My thought were simply that the line `send_mail()` either includes or doesn't include tabs. And the line "counter = 0" must match this exactly. So simply rewriting the latter line with spaces does nothing if `send_mail()` includes tabs

Comment: @driax replacing all tabs in the file will certainly solve the problem though, and it is best practice.

Comment: Ok I removed all tabs in my file and replaced it with spaces, works now. Thanks!